# Using parquet-avro library in Java to read parquet file written using pyarrow

Tags: java, python, pandas, parquet

I am writing a dataframe to parquet using pyarrow in python.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
         "numbers": [1, 2, 3],
         "colors": ["red", "white", "blue"],
         "dates":['2019-12-16', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-16'],
         "codes": [None, None, None]
        }
    )
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, "filename")
```

Parquet file when read in Java (or in Sublime Text configured with parquet-tools) is:

```
{"numbers":1,"codes":"R1"}
{"numbers":2,"codes":"G1"}
{"numbers":3,"codes":"B1"}
```

The code I am using to read the parquet is this:

```
class Parquet {
  private List<SimpleGroup> data;
  private List<Type> schema;

  public Parquet(List<SimpleGroup> data, List<Type> schema) {
    this.data = data;
    this.schema = schema;
  }

  public List<SimpleGroup> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public List<Type> getSchema() {
    return schema;
  }
}

 public static Parquet getParquetData(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<SimpleGroup> simpleGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    ParquetFileReader reader = ParquetFileReader.open(HadoopInputFile.fromPath(new Path(filePath), new Configuration()));
    MessageType schema = reader.getFooter().getFileMetaData().getSchema();
    List<Type> fields = schema.getFields();
    PageReadStore pages;
    while ((pages = reader.readNextRowGroup()) != null) {
      long rows = pages.getRowCount();
      MessageColumnIO columnIO = new ColumnIOFactory().getColumnIO(schema);
      RecordReader recordReader = columnIO.getRecordReader(pages, new GroupRecordConverter(schema));

      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        SimpleGroup simpleGroup = (SimpleGroup) recordReader.read();
        simpleGroups.add(simpleGroup);
      }
    }
    reader.close();
    return new Parquet(simpleGroups, fields);
  }
}
```

While debugging I found that though schema has all the columns, in data we see only non-null columns.
[image]

Has anybody seen this behavior? Is there any option in the parquet-avro library to not have this  'optimization'?

Thanks

Comment: Please paste the exact code you are using into your question. The linked blog post contains several snippets.

Comment: Updated with the code